# How to join an enumerated char list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a function that converts *RNA* to *DNA*. The input comes in as a char list: `'ATCG'` so I loop through each letter and use a map to get the converted letter. Simple.

The problem is after enumerating the character list I can't merge it back to a char list. Enum.join returns a string, `to_charlist` just returns a list of the character points, and I don't see any other functions that could help.

Here is my code:

```
def to_rna(dna) do
  dna_to_rna = %{
   'G' => 'C',
   'C' => 'G',
   'T' => 'A',
   'A' => 'U'
  }
  Enum.map(dna, fn(letter) ->
    Map.get(dna_to_rna, [letter])
  end)    
end
```

This outputs a list of characters:  `['U', 'G', 'C']`. How do I convert this list into a charlist: `'UGC'`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Concatenating the Lists

You can use [`Enum.concat/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#concat/1) at the end to join the lists:

```
Enum.concat(['U', 'A', 'G', 'C'])      # =>   'UAGC'
```

---

### Using a Reducer

You can also use [`reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) instead of [`map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) and do it one step:

```
def to_rna(dna) do
  mapping = %{
   'G' => 'C',
   'C' => 'G',
   'T' => 'A',
   'A' => 'U'
  }

  Enum.reduce(dna, [], fn(letter, acc) ->
    acc ++ Map.get(mapping, [letter])
  end)  
end
```

This will give `'UAGC'` for the input value `'ATCG'`.

Comment: Why does this work? It seems like it should be returning the same thing as my function. Also is there anyway to actually convert the enumerated list back into a regular list?

Comment: The point of a reducer is to 'reduce' a collection into a single value. This method accumulates all values of your list by joining them together using `++`

Comment: Yes but a list could be a single value depending on how you look at it.

Comment: For your second question, you need to understand that `'UAGC'` is already a list (albeit a list of codepoints). If you want it to convert it to `['U', 'A', 'G', 'C']` (i.e. a list of lists), you can use `Enum.chunk('UAGC', 1)`

Answer (score 6):

Not to [necropost](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Necropost), but I recently started learning Elixir and have been doing some Exercism problems as well.
This answer might be somewhat off-topic, since I'm proposing a similar solution *without* the use of a `Map`.

The Exercism problem's (`rna-transcription`, no link) function input, as described above, is a
[charlist](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists)
and expects a chartist as output.
From the charlist documentation:

> A charlist is a list of integers where all the integers are valid code points.

We can also look at Exercism's provided
[function spec](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html#function-specifications), `@spec to_rna([char]) :: [char]`, and see a charlist is both the expected input and output.
The [built-in types documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#built-in-types) shows us `charlist()` is the same as `[char()]`.

From the question's description, we see there's a 1:1 mapping of code point to code point. A map is a totally valid way to represent that, but I'd posit we can solve the problem just using iteration and pattern matching.

I feel a salient point was left out of some of the other answers: why are the `Enum` elements wrapped with `[]`, e.g. `Enum.map(dna, fn x -> Map.get(%{...}, [x])`?
It's because each iterated element is a single character, i.e. an integer/code point. By wrapping the value in `[]`, that code point is turned into a chartist with one character, e.g. `'C'`. The keys/values of the example `Map` are all single-element charlists. This successfully maps nucleotide-to-nucleotide, but it also changes the element's type from integer to charlist.
This results in a list of charlists, not a single/flat charlist, e.g. `'GCTA'` turns into `['C', 'G', 'A', 'U']` (a list of charlists), which is *not* the same as `'CGAU'`.
As pointed out in other solutions, `Enum.concat/1` and `Enum.flat_map/2` are both ways to turn the list of lists into a flat chartist. From The
[`flat_map` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map/2):

> ... conceptually, [`flat_map/2`] is similar to a combination of `map/2` and `concat/1`.

So, can we perform the mapping *without* the intermediate character lists? I believe the answer is "yes."
Instead of converting each code point into a charlist, why not just convert the code point to the expected code point directly?

From the doc links above, we know code points are just integers. To demonstrate:

```
iex[1]> Enum.each('CGAU', &IO.inspect/1)
67
71
65
85
:ok
```

This means we really just need to map the integer/code point values to other code point values.
However, I feel mapping integer values a bit unnatural when we're trying to map character literals.
Fortunately, Elixir gives us the `?` symbol, which represents the integer value of a character literal ([more here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#unicode-and-code-points)), e.g.

```
iex> ?G
71
```

```
iex[1]> 'ATCG' == [?A, ?T, ?C, ?G]
true
iex[2]> [?A, ?T, ?C, ?G] == [65, 84, 67, 71]
true
```

Using this, we can directly convert individual code points to their respective code point mapping while still using the character literal, e.g.
`?G -> ?C`. You can still make a `Map` of these, e.g. `%{?G => ?C, ...}`; however, I feel this is a good scenario for pattern matching.
We can use `Enum.map` with a function with multiple clauses.
With this approach, the individual code points are mapped 1:1, resulting in a new flat, charlist -- allowing us to forgo the need of `concat` or `flat_map` (and save a bit of typing).

```
@spec to_rna([char]) :: [char]
def to_rna(dna) do
    Enum.map(dna, fn
        ?G -> ?C
        ?C -> ?G
        ?T -> ?A
        ?A -> ?U
    end)
end
```

Comment: I am a mentor on the Elixir track on Exercism.io.
This is the prefered solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [Enum.concat](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#concat/1) to solve it:

```
  def to_rna(dna) do
    dna
    |> Enum.map(fn x -> Map.get(%{'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U'}, [x]) end)
    |> Enum.concat()
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  :lists.flatten(['A', 'B','C'])
```

This is erlang function in the lists module. In elixir you can call on erlang functions as :.

- check out http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1

Comment: please edit the answer and show at least where the function is from.

Comment: added the info.